# Handling file download from ajax get request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a python CGI server to handle a cgi-bin request that I am making from an ajax call.

I'm trying to download the information I'm receiving on the Python side from my browser, using a button that triggers the ajax call.

I have tried some different things I saw on StackOverflow, but nothing has helped.

```
function issueDownloadCmd(port) {
    var statusURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/cgi-bin/sod_log.py" + "?" + "down" + port.toString();

    $.ajaxSetup({ 'cache': true });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: statusURL,
        error: function (xhr, desc, exception) {
            $('#traceStatus').html("Fail: response=" + xhr.status + "\nbecause: " + desc + "\nexception: " + exception);
        },
        success: function (data) {            
            console.log("data was downloaded");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no errors. i get response from the browser whenever i check the inspect tool but no errors

Comment: You can't download files to your disk via AJAX. The file's data ends up in the `data` variable of your "success" function instead of on your disk. Visit the URL with a normal request instead. In JavaScript you can do this with something like window.location or window.open